# How to do resampling by month in R?

Tags: r

Im trying to find a way to resample a time series data by month in r.

this can be done using data frame resampling in Python. Is there a way we can do the same in R?

Initial data frame

```
     Date       Qty
05/25/2018       10
08/20/2018       15
10/15/2018       25
```

Should be changed to

```
    Date        Qty
03/01/2018       0
04/01/2018       0
05/01/2018       10
06/01/2018       0
07/01/2018       0
08/01/2018       15
09/01/2018       0
10/01/2018       25
11/01/2018       0
12/01/2018       0
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you simply looking for a way to choose a random sample drawn from your initial data? If so, why does your initial data frame have fewer observations than the resampled data?

Comment: May be resample is not the right word. But I'm trying to achieve my final monthly  continuous data frame from initial data frame which is not continuous.

Comment: I used the term resampling because we can achieve the same using resample() method in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a faster way of doing this, but it works.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#create the data
data <- data.frame(Date = c(ymd(20180525), ymd(20180820), ymd(20181015)),
                   Qty = c(10, 15, 25))

#generate a data frame of all months
Months <- data.frame(Month = seq.Date(ymd(20180301), ymd(20181201), by = "month"))


data %>% 
  #determine the month/year of the Date
  mutate(Month = ymd(year(Date) * 10000 + month(Date) * 100 + 1)) %>% 
  #sum Qty to the month/year level
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise(Qty = sum(Qty)) %>%
  #join to all months
  right_join(Months, by = c("Month" = "Month")) %>% 
  #replace any NA's with 0
  mutate(Qty = replace(Qty, is.na(Qty), 0))

        Month   Qty
        <date> <dbl>
1 2018-03-01     0
2 2018-04-01     0
3 2018-05-01    10
4 2018-06-01     0
5 2018-07-01     0
6 2018-08-01    15
7 2018-09-01     0
8 2018-10-01    25
9 2018-11-01     0
10 2018-12-01     0
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` and `lubridate` approach

```
library( data.table )
library( lubridate )

dt <- fread("Date       Qty
05/25/2018       10
08/20/2018       15
10/15/2018       25", header = TRUE)

#create data.table with first day of each month
dt.months <- data.table( Date = seq( as.Date("2018-01-01"), length=12, by="1 month"))

#set Date as actual date, and floor to the first day of the month
dt[, Date := floor_date( as.Date( Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "month" )]
#sum qty by month (noft needed in this example)

#left join
result <- dt[dt.months, on = "Date", nomatch = NA ]
#replace NA with 0
result[is.na(result)] <- 0

result
Date Qty
# 1: 2018-01-01   0
# 2: 2018-02-01   0
# 3: 2018-03-01   0
# 4: 2018-04-01   0
# 5: 2018-05-01  10
# 6: 2018-06-01   0
# 7: 2018-07-01   0
# 8: 2018-08-01  15
# 9: 2018-09-01   0
# 10: 2018-10-01  25
# 11: 2018-11-01   0
# 12: 2018-12-01   0
```